# Not able to use UIView in NSObject Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum _NSBubbleType
{
BubbleTypeMine = 0,
BubbleTypeSomeoneElse = 1
} NSBubbleType;

@interface NSBubbleData : NSObject

@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSBubbleType type;
@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets insets;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *avatar;

- (id)initWithText:(NSString *)text date:(NSDate *)date type:      (NSBubbleType)type;
+ (id)dataWithText:(NSString *)text date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type;
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type;
+ (id)dataWithImage:(UIImage *)image date:(NSDate *)date type: (NSBubbleType)type;
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets;
+ (id)dataWithView:(UIView *)view date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets;
```

below is my object and .m class
    #import "NSBubble.h"
    #import

```
@implementation NSBubble

@synthesize datee,vieww,insetss,typee;

#pragma mark - Text bubble

const UIEdgeInsets textInsetsMine = {5, 10, 11, 17};
const UIEdgeInsets textInsetsSomeone = {5, 15, 11, 10};

+ (id)dataWithText:(NSString *)text date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type
{
    return [[NSBubble alloc] initWithText:text date:date type:type];
}

- (id)initWithText:(NSString *)text date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type
{
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
CGSize size = [(text ? text : @"") sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
label.text = (text ? text : @"");
label.font = font;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIEdgeInsets insets = (type == BubbleTypeMine ? textInsetsMine : textInsetsSomeone);
return [self initWithView:label date:date type:type insets:insets];
}


#pragma mark - Custom view bubble

+ (id)dataWithView:(UIView *)view date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets
{
return [[NSBubble alloc] initWithView:view date:date type:type insets:insets];
}

- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{

    vieww = view;
    datee = date;

    typee = type;
    insetss = insets;
}
return self;
}


@end
```

this is my table view

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "HeaderDataSource.h"
#import "NSBubbleTblCell.h"

@interface NSBubbleTblView : UITableView      <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet  id<UIBubbleTableViewDataSource> bubbleDataSource;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval snapInterval;

- (void) scrollBubbleViewToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

this is .m

```
#import "NSBubbleTblView.h"
#import "NSBubble.h"
#import "NSBubbleTblHeaderCell.h"

@interface NSBubbleTblView ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bubbleSection;

@end

@implementation NSBubbleTblView

@synthesize dataSource,snapInterval,bubbleSection;

#pragma mark - Initializators

- (void)initializator
{
// UITableView properties

self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
assert(self.style == UITableViewStylePlain);

self.delegate = self;
self.dataSource = self;

// UIBubbleTableView default properties

self.snapInterval = 120;

}

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) [self initializator];
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) [self initializator];
return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) [self initializator];
return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
if (self) [self initializator];
return self;
}

#pragma mark - Override

- (void)reloadData
{
self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
NSLog(@"%@",bubbleSection);
// Cleaning up
self.bubbleSection = nil;

// Loading new data
int count = 0;
self.bubbleSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (self.bubbleDataSource && (count = [self.bubbleDataSource rowsForBubbleTable:self]) > 0)
{
    NSMutableArray *bubbleData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        NSObject *object = [self.bubbleDataSource bubbleTableView:self dataForRow:i];
        assert([object isKindOfClass:[NSBubble class]]);
        [bubbleData addObject:object];

        [bubbleData sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
         {
             NSBubble *bubbleData1 = (NSBubble *)obj1;
             NSBubble *bubbleData2 = (NSBubble *)obj2;
             return [bubbleData1.datee compare:bubbleData2.datee];
         }];

        NSDate *last = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
        NSMutableArray *currentSection = nil;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            NSBubble *data = (NSBubble *)[bubbleData objectAtIndex:i];

            if ([data.datee timeIntervalSinceDate:last] > self.snapInterval)
            {
                currentSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [self.bubbleSection addObject:currentSection];
            }
            [currentSection addObject:data];
            last = data.datee;
        }
    }


}
 [super reloadData];
}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource implementation


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
int result = [self.bubbleSection count];

return result;

}


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {


 return [[self.bubbleSection objectAtIndex:section] count];


 }

 - (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

 // Header
 if (indexPath.row == 0)
 {
     return [NSBubbleTblHeaderCell height];
 }

 NSBubble *data = [[self.bubbleSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
 return data.insetss.top + data.vieww.frame.size.height + data.insetss.bottom;

 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

 // Header with date and time
 if (indexPath.row == 0)
 {
     static NSString *cellId = @"tblBubbleHeaderCell";
     NSBubbleTblHeaderCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
     NSBubble *data = [[self.bubbleSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:0];

     if (cell == nil) cell = [[NSBubbleTblHeaderCell alloc] init];

     cell.date = data.datee;

     return cell;
 }

 // Standard bubble
 static NSString *cellId = @"tblBubbleCell";
 NSBubbleTblCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
 NSBubble  *data = [[self.bubbleSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];

 if (cell == nil)

 cell = [[NSBubbleTblCell alloc] init];

 cell.data = data;

 return cell;

 }
```

Showing multiple  while run the project. its like out of the blue .Help would be must appreciated. their might be some problem with tableview and its datasource i think i am understanding how i can implement in this with this url  Someone help.

[image]

Comment: Missing UIKit import?

Comment: It shows another error like below

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[NSBubbleTblView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:9269
2015-07-27 16:53:23.807 Hansel[6740:143046] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource is not set'

Comment: I have made a custom table view with data source and table view cell so when i run the project it shows the above error.

Comment: That's another error. That's a error at runTime. There is no "UITableView" in the code you showed. We can't guess what's wrong.

Comment: ok hold on .. i will show you

Comment: Do you use storyboard? And if you do, did you create a ViewController and inside it add a TableView, or did you just add TableViewController

Comment: yes I am using story board and my view controller is ChatViewController and on this view controller i am adding a table view on view.

Comment: I think you forgot setting the class of ViewController to ChatViewController

Comment: if i import #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> it shows this datasource is not set exeption and if i don't it shows the multiple error like above

Comment: Is `initializator` called? It may be called in `awakeFromNib` (if that's the method called).

Comment: yes it was. i already did that @KutayDemireren

Comment: Then did you set the dataSource and delegate from tableView to view ?

Comment: No @KutayDemireren i am following  steps from the example <https://codeload.github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView/legacy.zip/master> and in that there is no setting between the table and delegate or datasource

Comment: Let me check that zip file.

Comment: i am using all header cell, table cell and tabelview and object programatically as per the example but error and exception is showing all the time.

Comment: Can't find any step by step in here, it is just a project? Where is the steps that you mentioned following.

Comment: is there any tutes for custom table , simple bubble table

Comment: There are lots of custom table tutorial find on the net. http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ is good or I like that more https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Comment: But before those, please try to set delegate and dataSource of tableView with controlDragging to the view, which at the top of view with small yellow box. I assume you know.

Comment: thankx @KutayDemireren nice to being with you.

Comment: You'r welcome. Hope we could help more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> ***Assertion failure in -[NSBubbleTblView
> _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:9269 2015-07-27
> 16:53:23.807 Hansel[6740:143046] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
> exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView
> dataSource is not set'
```

As you can see., this error: **UITableView dataSource is not set** indicates that you table view data source is not set. You have to connect table view with data source in interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

you need to import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` . It adds the necessary UIImage, UITableView, UIView etc.

Comment: i know but it is giving another exception while run the program

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[NSBubbleTblView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:9269 2015-07-27 16:53:23.807 Hansel[6740:143046] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource is not set'

Comment: Yeah I know right, I wrote the answer before you wrote it. Now thinking for the new error. Can you look my suggestion below your question @vikramsingh